# Run a specified command on error without try/catch in Matlab

Tags: matlab, error-handling, cells

I have a Matlab script consisting of several cells that should all be able to execute independently (i.e. I might need to execute one cell in order to execute another, but until I clear the workspace I should be able to execute the second cell again without executing the first one). The code in these cells sometimes fails (of course), and in case they do, I want to run a specific command.

Since the code spans across several independent cells, I can't use a try/catch block to accomplish this - not unless I put one try/catch block in each cell, which I don't want to. Each cell is pretty short (a few lines with function calls, mostly), so introducing a try/catch block in every cell would probably double the length of the script.

Specifically, I want to open a log file (`diary filename.log`) in the first cell, which closes automatically (`diary off`) after an error occurs (and is logged) from any cell. This setting should be on at least until the log file is closed again, and should be settable programatically (I want to set it in the same cell I open the log file).

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Why does your code fail?  Can you substitute if statements that support your code, assuming you are able to set these boundaries?

Comment: Is there a strong reason to use this cellular architecture for your code?  Perhaps there is something I don't understand about cell mode, but I always viewed it as a tool to help prototype commands.  Once you have something working that you like, you should encapsulate it in a function.

Comment: I use the cellular structure to be able to repeat parts of the code several times while only having to run other (slow) tasks once. In this specific case, I'm first building up a 3D geometry (slow) and then simulating a CT scan (much faster) while varying a couple of parameters. I would like to log each run, regardless of how finished my code is, but I'd like each run to be in a different log file. I open a log at the start of simulation, named after the timestamp, but if the code fails I want to close the diary to fix the problem, instead of having a gzillion failing runs in one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your code as a script, your best solution is to put a `try/catch` block around each cell.

Otherwise, you can create a function to wrap around your script. The function syntax allows you to set 'dbstop if error', so that code execution halts on an error which allows you to inspect variables and pinpoint why things went wrong.

```
function output = run(listOfCells,input)
%#RUN evaluates the cells listed in listOfCells

try

diary filename.log

if any(listOfCells==1)
%# evaulate cell 1

end

if any(listOfCells==2)
%# evaluate cell 2

end

...

catch
%# close the diary in case of error
diary off
end %# try
```

Comment: How do I execute this? By calling `run([1 2 4], 'my_script_name.m')`, or some other way?

Comment: @Tomas Lycken: You copy-paste cell #1 into the first if-clause, cell #2 into the second if-clause etc. Don't forget to pass the necessary input arguments to the function. If the inputs are `a`,`b`, and `c`, you'd call `out = run([1 2 4],a,b,c)`

Comment: I probably won't use this (I'll just try to remember turning off the diary manually instead), but since it seems that Matlab doesn't have the funcitonality I want, this is probably one of the best workaround's there is.